# Netlogo : reproduce function IF two turtles meet

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create a function so that :

- when two turtles meet they reproduce
- if they have the same color they "hatch" 2
- if they don't have the same color they "hatch" 1

Here's my code and the part I'm interested in is `to reproduce`:

```
turtles-own [energy]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to reproduce
  ask turtles [
    if energy > 1 [
      set energy -1
      hatch 2 [ set energy 1 ]
    ]
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles number [ 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "person"
  set color blue
  set energy (2)
  ]
  
  ask one-of turtles [
    set color green]
   
end


to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    forward 1
      ]
end


to go
  if ticks >= 500 [ stop ]
  move-turtles
  check-death
  reproduce
  tick
end


to check-death
  ask turtles [
    if energy < 0 [ die ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please state what you have tried so far and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three primitives that you will need here:

- `turtles-here` returns an agentset of all the turtles on the same patch as the turtle calling it. This also includes the turtle doing the asking
- `other` takes an agentset of turtles and returns that agentset but without the turtle who did the asking
- `any?` takes an agentset and looks whether or not there are any agents in that agentset

Taken together, you get:

```
ask turtles [
    if any? other turtles-here [ 
        if energy > 1 [
            set energy -1
            hatch 2 [ set energy 1 ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Do note that this means that a pair of turtles will reproduce twice, since both turtles find another turtle and thus reproduce.